# matplotlib legend based on edge width

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, networkx

I have the following network:

[image]

I want to create a legend based on the edge width. Like the following (numbers are not accurate):

[image]

I have created legend for the node colors easily by colormaps, but legend based on the width, is more problematic.

Should I just create a new subgraph and plot the lines and width by myself? Using this method, I find it very complicated, because there are some edge cases to take care of, and some brute assumptions to make like the number of lines to plot (although I guess it's ok to assume there are 8~10+ lines with different widths).

So I just wrote a simple example, having a legend of the node colors, and a very simple basic starter I did to check out the width legend.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edge('a','b',weight=6)
graph.add_edge('a','c',weight=2)
graph.add_edge('c','d',weight=1)
graph.add_edge('c','e',weight=7)
graph.add_edge('c','f',weight=9)
graph.add_edge('a','d',weight=3)
edges = graph.edges()
edges_weight_list = [graph[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]
n_nodes = graph.number_of_nodes()
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, pos, width = edges_weight_list)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos)
mcp = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, pos,
                             node_color=list(range(n_nodes)),
                             cmap='Blues')
limits = plt.axis('off')  # turn of axis


# width lines
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
edges_weight_list = sorted(edges_weight_list)
for i, current_weight in enumerate(edges_weight_list):
    x=[0, 1]
    y=[i, i]
    plt.plot(x,y, linewidth=current_weight, color='black')

plt.colorbar(mcp)
limits = plt.axis('off')  # turn of axis
plt.show()
```

This plots:

[image]

(Obviously in a real life example I won't iterate over all the lines).

I'm using Python 3.6, networkx 2.2, matplotlib 2.2.2.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Don't you get your desired output?

Comment: @Mr.T perhaps for a short term, but I want to apply this function to many files. If I do it like this, I will probably return to this function for fixes. For example, if I would want to make the graph larger, then I would probably need to change some variables.

Comment: I don't know networkx and its functionality. Can't you determine the minimal and maximal linewidth and weight and then create five additional intermediate lines between those values for the legend?

Comment: Yes this is what I'll probably do.

Comment: networkx plotting is based on matplotlib, and something you could look for is the use of proxy artists to build a legend.  But it would still likely require iterating over all the lines to construct a good subset to include in the legend; and also some binning logic if you have continuous weights.

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#proxy-legend-handles

Comment: I added my answer. Tell me what you people think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually instead of plotting the lines, and then adding the text manually - I created a list of empty `Line2D` with a label and width - and created the legend for them.

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

lines = []
edges_weight_list = sorted(edges_weight_list)
for i, width in enumerate(edges_weight_list):
    lines.append(Line2D([],[], linewidth=width, color='black'))

legend2 = plt.legend(lines, edges_weight_list, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.5), frameon=False)
```

[image]